# Intersection of smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

I am wondering under which conditions the intersection of two smooth manifolds, say $X$ and $Y$, is a smooth manifold. I know that if they intersect transversally then the intersection is a manifold.

Now suppose that the manifolds do not intersect transversally. Can the intersection still be a manifold? And can the formula $\operatorname{codim}(X\cap Y)=\operatorname{codim}(X)+\operatorname{codim}(Y)$ still be valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it sure can. Consider $X=\{y=0\}$ and $Y=\{y=x^2\}\subset\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason I was not accepting that a single point is a manifold. Thank you!

Comment: Well, we can move this same sort of example into any number of dimensions you want :)

Comment: Just take $X = Y$, the intersection is the smooth manifold $X$. @dlc

Comment: @JohnMa: But that will violate the codimension condition the OP wanted. :)